# Persist a navbar in Next.js with custom `App`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm learning Next.js and stumbled upon this issue. Back in the old ways, this is how you would use the navbar across all pages

```
return (
    <Container>
        <Navbar />
        <Component {...pageProps}/>
    </Container>

   )
```

but now the documentation is written using functional components https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app. I'm trying something like this but so far it doesn't work

```
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
 }
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to make this work?

Comment: Check on https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/layout-component

Comment: I guess they recommend this way now. The next-render will take care of detecting similar layouts between pages, and only update the changing parts of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore my last response, this will cause an unnecessary render, use:

```
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you remove your other response since your'e telling users to ignore it please ?